# Different markevery for each column in a pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like in the example below with three columns of data that are very similar, to the point where the plots essentially lie on top of one another. I would like the reader not to be confused by this point. If there were only two plots, a line and marker could be used for this purpose. But I have three, so any markers themselves collide. markevery seemed like a good bet, but the same number gets applied to the columns so again I have this collision. I haven't had luck with the cycler or with using a list as an argument. Is there a way to do this? I am open to alternative solutions but constrained by accessibility rules not to use color.

```
cases = [None,8,16]
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(markevery=cases)

t=np.arange(1000)
data={"y0": np.cos(2.*np.pi*t/400.),"y1": np.cos(2*np.pi*t/400.)+0.01,"y2": np.cos(2*np.pi*t/400.)-0.01}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=t,data=data)
df.plot(color="black",style=["-","v","0"],markersize=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you could try. This is a little tricky just cause normally color makes it easier to differentiate lines, but that's not an option for you. You can try experimenting with different `marker`, `markevery`, and `markersize` values. You might also change the line styles (dotted, dashed, etc.).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cases = [None, 8, 16]

t = np.arange(1000)
data = {
    "y0": np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * t / 400.0),
    "y1": np.cos(2 * np.pi * t / 400.0) + 0.01,
    "y2": np.cos(2 * np.pi * t / 400.0) - 0.01,
}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=t, data=data)
ax = df.plot(color="black", legend=False)

markers = ["s", "o", "D"]
spacing = [8, 22, 31]
for i, line in enumerate(ax.get_lines()):
    line.set_marker(markers[i])
    line.set_markevery(spacing[i])
    line.set_markersize(spacing[i] / 4)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]